# Anaconda update downloads all packages?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, anaconda3

I have Anaconda installed with 1 environment only `base`

I ran `conda update -c anaconda --all` and I think it's downloading all packages from scratch?!?!

It's taking more than 15-20 mins already. Did I do something wrong? I just wanted to update those packages which needed to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

`conda update` - update packages

`-c` - Additional channel to search for packages. If not there, ignores this option

`--update-all, --all`   Update all installed packages in the environment.

When you do `--all` it updates all the packages in the activated environment.

If you want to update specific packages then use the following command

`conda update scipy`

In order to find which all packages are outdated - `conda search --outdated`

Comment: So what does that mean? That is the command documentation, yes. So... ?

Comment: @peter.petrov Updated my answer